# How to load pre-existing database (created from Excel) with SQLiteAssetHelper into Android device?

Tags: android, database, excel, sqlite

I am trying to load my pre-existing database into my android device.

I used these steps:

1. Use external library `SQLiteAssetHelper` available on [github](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)
2. Then according to the documentation: write a wrapper class

   ```
   public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
       private static final String TAG = "DataBaseHelper";
       private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test.db";
       private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

       public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
           super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
       }

       private static final String TABLE_EXAMPLE = "example"; //example is the table name
       private static final String COLUMN_EXAMPLE_A = "A";

       public String searchSomething() {
           SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

           SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase(); //database name
           //parameters in query method
           String tables = "table"; //
           String[] projectionln = {"test"}; //which columns to return, null return all
           String selection = "row_name = example"; //which rows to return, formatted as WHERE clause excluding WHERE
           String[] selectionArgs = null; //you may include ? in selection which will be filled in by selectionArgs in order
           String groupBy = null; //how to group rows
           String having = null; //filter which row groups to include in cursor
           String sortOrder = null; //how to order the rows

           qb.setTables(tables);
           Cursor cursor = qb.query(db, projectionln, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, sortOrder);
           cursor.moveToFirst();
           return cursor.getString(1);
       }
   ```

   }
3. Instantiate the wrapper class in an `Activity` to use the database

Like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DataBaseHelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        final String name = db.searchSomething();

    }
}
```

4. Place your database file into your project under `main/src/assets/databases` for instance if you database filename is test.db, the file is in main/src/assets/databases/test.db
5. [Add to your database special meta-information like described here](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

After I have done all this I am left with errors which make me believe that my file format for my database is not yet good. I used a database provided by the library on github and that worked.

```
06-16 13:38:56.957    9281-9281/com.mycompany.programname E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mycompany.programname, PID: 9281
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.programname/com.mycompany.programname.mainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.getVersion()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.getVersion()' on a null object reference
            at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:178)
            at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:254)
            at com.mycompany.programname.DataBaseHelper.searchSomething(DataBaseHelper.java:75)
            at com.mycompany.programname.HomescreenActivity.onCreate(HomescreenActivity.java:23)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Now my question is, how do you get the database file in the proper sql `db` format? I think that this must be the problem. Right now I have an excel document which I convert to sql format using the import function from the program [DB browser of SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/). Then I save the database, which then has the sql extension, I searched on internet how to convert it to .db and I found that you could simply change the extension name. But I don't think that's true. Hope someone has any idea or tips because I am stuck at this for over a day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Right now I have an excel document which I convert to sql format.

I do not know what you consider "sql format" to be.

> I searched on internet how to convert it to .db and I found that you could simply change the extension name. Is this true?

No.

If "sql format" means "a plain text file containing a series of SQL statements", you can try using that with any number of SQLite-equipped tools, such as the **`sqlite3`** program that comes with SQLite itself. Or, try the SQLite clients you find via a search on `sqlite clients` on your favorite search engine.

Or, write yourself a program that runs on your development machine that converts your Excel data into a SQLite database. For example, [my book](https://commonsware.com/Android), in its APK edition, comes with a full-text index in the form of a pre-packaged SQLite database that I load in via `SQLiteAssetHelper`. Part of my book-publishing process is to create that database, using a Ruby script and the SQLite Ruby gem.